# Swift Button class

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

So, I'm following the tutorial for making a Minesweeper in Swift (https://www.makeschool.com/online-courses/tutorials/learn-swift-by-example) using Xcode 9 and latest Swift
I made a class for Square button

```
import Cocoa


class SquareButton :NSButton {
    let squareSize: CGFloat
    var square:Square
    init(squareModel:Square,squareSize:CGFloat) {
        self.square = squareModel
        self.squareSize = squareSize

        let x = CGFloat(self.square.col) * squareSize
        let y = CGFloat(self.square.row) * squareSize
        let squareFrame = CGRect(x: x,y: y,width: squareSize,height: squareSize)
        super.init(frame :squareFrame)

    }
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

( Yes, I know that tutorial was made for IOS, single view application, but I'm trying best to translate it. )

But when I try to initialize it

```
let square = board.squares[row][col]
let squareSize:CGFloat = self.boardView.frame.width / CGFloat(boardSize)
let squareButton = SquareButton(squareModel: Square, squareSize: squareSize);
```

It gives me an error : 
Cannot invoke initializer for type 'SquareButton' with an argument list of type '(squareModel: Square.Type, squareSize: CGFloat)'

I technically do super.init, so it wants a frame. I don't know why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let squareButton = SquareButton(squareModel: Square, squareSize: squareSize);
                                             ^ this is your problem
```

You're passing `Square` (the type) rather than `square` (the instance you created of that type). Change the capital `S` to a lower-case `s`.

Comment: Oh, okay, didn't know it was that easy xD Thanks a lot !